# Excluding multiple terms from search results in Google Custom Search API

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-custom-search, google-api-python-client

```
devKey = 'FAUX123456789'
customSearchEngineId = 'FAUX123456789'

searchTermArray = ['happy pets valencia CA',
                   'pet doctor z tuscon AZ',
                   'best friends veterinary hospital crossville TN',
                   'pet pal animal shelter st petersburg FL']

termsToExclude = ['happy','pet','vet']

numberOfResults = 1

for eachSearchTerm in searchTermArray:
    service = build("customsearch", "v1", developerKey=devKey)
    results = service.cse().list(q=eachSearchTerm, cx=customSearchEngineId, num=numberOfResults, excludeTerms=termsToExclude)
    results = results['items']
    print(results)
```

According to the [google custom search API documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/customsearch/v1/python/latest/customsearch_v1.cse.html), *excludeTerms* takes a string value. As you can see, I tried plugging in an array of strings and it doesn't quite work. I actually tested each term independently and doing so produced different results each time. (please excuse the *dotcom* as I was unable to post the actual links)

Heres the results for each test:

- **termsToExclude = `''`** 
  *happypetsveterinarydotcom/* 
  *petdoctorxdotcom/* 
  *bestfriendsvetdotorg/* 
  *petpalanimalshelterdotcom/* 
   
  **termsToExclude = `['happy','pet','vet']`** 
  *happypetsveterinarydotcom/* 
  *ollinghillspetclinicdotcom/* 
  *bestfriendsvetdotorg/* 
  *petpalanimalshelterdotcom/* 
   
  **termsToExclude = `'happy'`** 
  *krisersdotcom/location/valencia/* 
  *valenciaanimalhospitaldotcom/reviews.html* 
  *bestfriendsvetdotorg/* 
  *petpalanimalshelterdotcom/adopt.php* 
   
  **termsToExclude = `'pet'`** 
  *teambusbydotcom/real-estate-news/home-and-design/60-design-happy-pets-from-around-the-world-60-photos*

  *www.zmansiondotcom/* 
  *www.bestfriendequinedotcom/* 
  *disneyworld.disney.godotcom/entertainment/magic-kingdom/character-meet-goofy-donald/*

   
  **termsToExclude = `'vet'`** 
  *happypetsveterinarydotcom/medical-records/my-pets-medical-records/*

  *www.staystudio6dotcom/en/motels.az.tucson.6002.html* 
  *langeanimalhospitaldotcom/josh-friends/* 
  *petpalanimalshelterdotcom/event/purrfect-poses-yoga/*

Now..

Google's [vague user-friendly documentation](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list) states the following:

**`excludeTerms`** *`string`* : Identifies a word or phrase that should not appear in any documents in the search results.

I'm not sure what *"any documents in the search results"* means exactly, but what I have discovered through this process is that when a single string is used, it appears to exclude URLs with the string value, **but** when an array of strings is used, it does not seem to have the same behavior at all. Can anyone explain this? Or please explain if there is proper a way to plug in an array of terms in this keyword `excludeTerms` parameter?

I want to clarify though, that what I am trying to accomplish is the ability to plug in an array of strings so that my results will specifically exclude URLs containing the terms in `termsToExclude`, so that I can get more desirable URLs in my results. Also, remember that when I used individual strings, that produced the desired result, whereas the arrays did not seem to work the same way.

Thanks for any info!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

excludeTerms is a flat string, so not sure what behavior you would get passing in an array.

Try it with

```
termsToExclude = 'happy pet vet'
```

Comment: Perfect solution! This is a classic case of me overthinking. There is nothing in the documentation regarding the excluding of multiple words. Was this supposed to be obvious? I cannot upvote your solution, but I can definitively say that this solved my problem! Thank you very much =)